# How to remove all devices from enterprise android management?

Tags: android, android-management-api

Is there any way to remove enterprise or all devices from enterprise in Android Management API ?

> Please note: I am already aware about api to remove single device i.e.
>   https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices/delete

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean if there is a programable way to do this? If so, then I think presently this is not possible using only the AMAPI. Providers that use the EMM API have this option using the [unenroll](https://developers.google.com/android/work/play/emm-api/v1/enterprises/unenroll) API call.

With the AMAPI, you may still be able to remove all devices by [listing](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices/list) them first and then call [delete](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices/delete) for each entry in the list. Be careful for the case where an enterprise contains hundreds or thousands of devices. Limit the amount of API calls over short periods of time. See [Usage Limits](https://developers.google.com/android/management/usage).

Answer (score 0):

To delete an enterprise.

1. Go to [Managed Play Store](https://play.google.com/work/apps)
2. Go to Admin Settings.
3. Delete Organization.

To delete all the devices from the enterprise.

1. You have to know all the devices associated with your enterprise by
   calling [Devices.list](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices/list).
2. Execute [Devices.delete](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices/delete) for each device

Answer (score 0):

"You could get the list of [enterprise Android](https://esper.io/hardware) devices from [devices.list](https://esper.io/hardware) and call [devices.delete](https://esper.io/hardware) on each of them.
"